# How to Create Only Edges Through OrientDb ETL

Tags: orientdb

I have a CSV file, having Id1 and Id2. Id1 and Id2 are vertex of two different classes. I want to make edge between Id1 and Id2. Can this be achieved by ETL?
Can we add something into the edge configuration of transformers to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume, that

- the two classes are `A` and `B`
- `A` has `Id1`
- `B` has `Id2`
- the class of the edge is `AtoB`
- `A` and `B` instances are present in the DB
- The AtoB.csv is like

  > AId,BId
  >
  > a1,b1
  >
  > a2,b2
  >
  > a2,b3

Then the following ETL config will do

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "...\AtoB.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": { } },
  "transformers": [
    { "merge": {
        "joinFieldName": "BId",
        "lookup": "B.Id2",
        "unresolvedLinkAction": "WARNING" } },
    { "vertex": { "class": "B" } },
    { "edge": {
        "class": "AtoB",
        "joinFieldName": "AId",
        "lookup": "A.Id1",
        "direction": "in" } },
    { "field": {
        "fieldNames": ["AId", "BId"],
        "operation": "remove" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/...",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "useLightweightEdges": false,
       "classes": [
         { "name": "A", "extends": "V" },
         { "name": "B", "extends": "V" },
         { "name": "AtoB", "extends": "E" }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result will be

- (a1) ➡ (b1)
- (a2) ➡ (b2)
- (a2) ➡ (b3)